# div popup not displaying / fade away issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a small piece of code as below. My issue is, despite the two divs (**overlay_connect_error** and **overlay_connect_success**) being identical, one of them : overlay_connect_error, does not display properly. Basically this div appears and fades away within a second whereas the other one is displaying fine, it stays there until I click on close link. The ajax call is working and returning the data fine. I am not able to figure out still where the error is. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Here is my code:

```
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".connectUser").click(function(){
           var loggedInUser = '<?php echo $user_id;?>';
           var otherUser = '<?php echo $otherUser_id;?>';
           var info = 'loggedInUser='+loggedInUser+'&otherUser='+otherUser;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "connect.php",
                    data: info,
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data.data=='success'){
                            $('#overlay_connect, #overlay-back').fadeOut(100);
                      $('#overlay_connect_success, #overlay-back-connect').fadeIn(500);

                    }else if(data.data=='error'){
                        $('#overlay_connect, #overlay-back').fadeOut(100);
                      $('#overlay_connect_error, #overlay-back-connect').fadeIn(500);
                    }   
                    }
                });
            });
        });

</script>


<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

#overlay-back {
    position   : fixed;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #1C1C1C;
    opacity    : 1.2;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 10;
    display    : none;
}    

#overlay-back-connect {
    position   : fixed;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #1C1C1C;
    opacity    : 1.2;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 10;
    display    : none;
}      

#overlay_connect {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    display  : none;
} 


#overlay_connect_error {
   position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    display  : none;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
}   

#overlay_connect_success {
   position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    display  : none;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
}  


</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
      function pop(div) {
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
      }
      function hide(div) {
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
      }

</script>


<style>
      .ontop {
        z-index: 999;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;       
        background-color: #cccccc;
        color: #aaaaaa;
        opacity: 1.9;
        filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
      }
      #popup {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -150px;
      }

 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.connect').on('click', function () {
    $('#overlay_connect, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500);
});
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="overlay-back"></div>
        <div align="center" style="position: relative; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; top: 80px;" id="overlay_connect">
          <span>
          <button id = "connectUser" class="connectUser" href="#" style="position: relative; top: 100px; align:center; color:white;">Connect with this person</button>
          <a href="home.php" style="position: relative; color:white; float: center;" onClick="hide('overlay-back')">Close</a>
          </span>
    </div> 

    <div id="overlay-back-connect"></div>
        <div align="center" style="position: relative; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; top: 50px;" id="overlay_connect_error">
          <span>
               <h3 style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;"> You are already connected with this person!! </h3><br/><p/>
              <a style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;" href="home.php">Close</a>
          </span>
    </div> 


     <div id="overlay-back-connect"></div>
        <div align="center" style="position: relative; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; top: 50px;" id="overlay_connect_success">
          <span>
               <h3 style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;"> You are now connected with this person!! </h3><br/><p/>
              <a style="position: relative; align:center; color:white;" href="home.php">Close</a>
          </span>
    </div>


<div>
    <a class="connect" id="connect" href="#">Connect</a>
</div>


<div>
    <a id="view_connections" href="connections.php">View Connections</a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: `filter: alpha(opacity = 50);` won't work. (And you don't need the `type` attribute on `<style>` and `<script>`.)

Comment: does it make any difference if I remove it? because it doesn't on my system

Comment: Well I don't know what's causing your problem, but that `filter` should *really* not work. You can remove those `type` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

First issue I see you have two elements with

```
id='overlay-back-connect'
```

lines 164 and 173

try removing them from your fade in options on lines 20 and 24

also alter the z values if you want something above another item if not remove z values from your style.

Merge two style blocks into one as there is no need to split them and move your script down to the end of the page as it needs to run after elements are loaded up

Comment: I did that already, doesn't work out, plus if in that case overlay_connect_success should not work too,  but it does

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises because of 2 html elements with same id as mentioned by 
AAnkudovich

The code is misbehaving when you are trying to fade in using the below code.
$('#overlay_connect_error, **#overlay-back-connect**').fadeIn(500);

Check this below plunker. I have made few changes to make it work on plunker and moved your code in plunker files structure.

https://plnkr.co/edit/AHUTLgFssxjJjDvUdcYT?p=preview

```
 <div id="overlay-back-connect-2"></div>


 <div id="overlay-back-connect-1"></div>
```